# Replace double quotes to string empty

Tags: asp.net

I want to remove `"Portugal"` remove double quotes and replace it with string empty what to do i am using `Replace("""," ")` but this not working

Comment: Try this `Replace("\""," ")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslash n instead:

```
Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

The backslash ("\") character is a special escape character used to indicate other special characters such as quotation marks (\"). For other special escape characters, you can refer to this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx